# How to set Axis Title in asp.net chart controls

Tags: asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts, microsoft-chart-controls

[image]

The AxisX title is "Date". But how can I change its direction? I would like to see "Date" horizontally.

The AxisX Labels direction is set like this:

```
chartCalls.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did u set chartArea1.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add MyChart.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've just tried that and it doesn't solve my issue. In addition, I don't think this is particularly related to the "Series" but to the "Chart"

Answer (score 0):

Put TextAlign="Horizontal" like this

```
   <AxisX Title="" LineColor="green" LineWidth="3" TextOrientation="Horizontal">
                                                <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                                            </AxisX>
```